# How can Bunyan be used to save logs into a specific file?

Tags: node.js, bunyan

My NodeJS app is acting buggy and I want to properly log everything that is happening while it is being used.

I came across [Bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) and it looks great. Except, like all other "loggers" it simply prints to `stdout` which makes it very hard for me to properly analyse what is going on.

Is there any way I can get Bunyan to always output to some file `logs.json` for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should log even if your app is not buggy. Anyway, did you actually read the documents? You use a stream:

```
var bunyanOpts = {
    name: 'myapp',
    streams: [
    {
        level: 'debug',
        stream: process.stdout       // log INFO and above to stdout
    },
    {
        level: 'info',
        path: '/var/tmp/logs.json'  // log ERROR and above to a file
    }
  ]
};

var logger = Bunyan.createLogger(bunyanOpts);
```

Now to view the log:

```
$ tail -f /var/tmp/logs.json | bunyan -o short
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The documents were not clear, I didn't see mention of the path. Stream doesn't do me anything because I don't want to have to watch the logs live

Comment: Streams have nothing to do with necessarily watching the logs live. They are just what other logging systems call "transports", places to write log information to.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, "Is there any way I can get Bunyan to always output to some file logs.json for example?"